# Why running a same script in different location cause errors?

Tags: python

I try to run a script that's using third party module (completely install by `pip install module`) in Ubuntu 13.10. This script located in NTFS partition.

```
import foo

API_KEY = "xxx"
api = foo.FOO(APIKEY)
```

and it's return error like

```
$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import foo
  File "/media/path/to/project/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    api = foo.Foo(API_KEY)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Foo'
```

but when I copy a same code to `~/Desktop/test.py` then it's work correctly. Is script's location cause these error or if it's not what's the problem?

Comment: Looks like it could be script location, atleast from what you have wrote. Can you try copying in 2-3 different places and try running from there and see how script reacts, And post that also here, so that we can understand better why it is giving the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether there is `foo.py` file in the directory. If there's one, it could prevent importing the module you want.

Issuing following command in both directory will give you the path of foo module:

```
python -c "import foo; print(foo.__file__)"
```

If you find there's unexpected `foo.py`, rename it or remove it. (Make sure there's no `foo.pyc` remain)

Comment: I found some file using duplicate name. So, it's call fake file (that haven't any attributes) and got errors, Thanks!